# Keyboard shortcut for moving focus to a different screen

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, mission-control

I am new to using Mac.

I have been using a multi-monitor setup. Specifically, I have two monitors. Each of the monitor have multiple spaces.

> ````````````````````````````
> ```````````````````````````
> `    1     `              `
> `          `       2.     `
> ````````````              `
>            `              `
>            ````````````````
> ````````````````````````````

Now (`.`) represent I have cursor in that screen. Now if I go ahead and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd>, I can move between the Spaces in screen 2. But if I want to move to another Space of screen 1, I have to:

1. Move my mouse cursor to screen 1

> ````````````````````````````
> ```````````````````````````
> `    1.    `              `
> `          `       2      `
> ````````````              `
>            `              `
>            ````````````````
> ````````````````````````````

2. Then use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd> to move between Spaces.

Is there any way I can skip the operation of moving my cursor to the different screen by mouse and do it my keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

There's a MacOS window manager inspired by xmonad called [Amethyst](https://ianyh.com/amethyst/) which has some key-bindings (default) <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to cycle the mouse between screens. There's more it can do of course.